# Prove that there exists $c∈(0,1)$ such that $\int_0^c{xf(x) \, dx} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Given a continuous function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_0^1{f(x)\, dx} = 0$ Prove that there exists $c∈(0,1)$ such that $\int_0^c{xf(x) \, dx} = 0$

---

I found a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4506834/1215260). It goes like this:
Let $G(x) = \int_{0}^{x} t f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$, and suppose that $G(c) \neq 0$ for all $c \in (0, 1)$. Then by IVT, either

- (Case 1) $G > 0$ on $(0, 1)$, or
- (Case 2) $G < 0$ on $(0, 1)$.

However,

\begin{align*}
0
= \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{G'(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= G(1) + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{G(x)}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

This is $ > 0 $ in Case 1 and $ < 0$ in Case 2, a contradiction.

---

**My doubt** is that how they got $$0= G(1) + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{G(x)}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$?

Comment: The integral is improper, though...

Comment: It looks like they used integration by parts, with $u=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ and $dv=G'(x)\,dx$. The problem, though is that written that way the integral is improper at $x=0$, so you cannot evaluate $\frac{G(x)}{x}\Bigm|_{0}^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original author here. I agree that the equality is not trivial. I am so accustomed to this type of computation that I omitted some details that might help untrained readers:

**1.** By performing integration by parts, for any $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{\varepsilon}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{\varepsilon}^{1} \frac{G'(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \left[ \frac{G(x)}{x} \right]_{\varepsilon}^{1}  + \int_{\varepsilon}^{1} \frac{G(x)}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= G(1) - \frac{G(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon} + \int_{\varepsilon}^{1} \frac{G(x)}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \tag{*}
\end{align*}

**2.** It is not hard to show that

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{G(x)}{x^2} = \frac{f(0)}{2} $$

In other words, if we define

$$ H(x) = \begin{cases}
G(x)/x^2, & x \in (0, 1] \\
f(0)/2, & x = 0
\end{cases} $$

then $H$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, and $\text{(*)}$ becomes

$$ \int_{\varepsilon}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= G(1) - \varepsilon H(\varepsilon) + \int_{\varepsilon}^{1} H(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

So by letting $\varepsilon \to 0^+$, the desired relation

$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= G(1) + \int_{0}^{1} H(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

is obtained.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts. Integrate $G'(x)$ and differentiate $\frac1x$.

Comment: Hello. What were the two functions used? $G'(x)$ and $1/x$? The formula of by parts is this right $\int_a^b f(x) g^{\prime}(x) d x=\left.f(x) g(x)\right|_{x=a} ^{x=b}-\int_a^b f^{\prime}(x) g(x) d x$ so what are we going to integrate here

Comment: @zaemon_23 Thanks for your comment. In this case, $f(x)=\frac1x$.

Comment: The integral is improper, though; you can't evaluate $\frac{G(x)}{x}$ at $0$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin We can evaluate the limit as it approaches $0$ to get zero by L'hopital.

Comment: @KamalSaleh: We can do the limit, but the integral is improper, so it needs to be set up *as a limit*, and not simply as an evaluation.